# background repeat only at the borders of my box

Tags: html, css

I have a nav to which I want to add a background image, because if I add the normal image it screws up the flex, and I wanted it to be repeated but only around the edges. I don't know if there is any way to achieve this.

My current code:

```css
nav {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  /*background-image: url(../Imagenes/navmusic.png);*/
  /*bogus img used for the snippet here*/
  background-image: url(https://pixabay.com/get/gbcda7058a3885ac11a062304ad9ba8647e6c3457ba65616142693813b48ad64d1b61c96e7a19f19e0a5611ce600767961015c603d8c3dcc524b690b66394d497a42e9f1f38c9fcc70f56bd0b5933aaea_640.jpg);
  background-size: 20%;
  background-position-x: right;
  background-position-y: -20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="Formulario.html">Formulario</a>
</nav>
```

I have tried to add it as a normal image but I don't know how to use the flex very well yet and it gives me problems since it counts it as an element of the flex and in the end I can't do what I want.

[That's what I have and I would like the image to be repeated just on the other side.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuoJk.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do :

```css
  background: url("https://pixabay.com/get/gbcda7058a3885ac11a062304ad9ba8647e6c3457ba65616142693813b48ad64d1b61c96e7a19f19e0a5611ce600767961015c603d8c3dcc524b690b66394d497a42e9f1f38c9fcc70f56bd0b5933aaea_640.jpg") left ,url("https://pixabay.com/get/gbcda7058a3885ac11a062304ad9ba8647e6c3457ba65616142693813b48ad64d1b61c96e7a19f19e0a5611ce600767961015c603d8c3dcc524b690b66394d497a42e9f1f38c9fcc70f56bd0b5933aaea_640.jpg") right;
```

Also instead of using `background-size: 20%;` and `background-position-y: -20px;`, you could use [`background-size: contain;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size#contain).

```css
nav {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #333 !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  background: url("https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-images/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg") left ,
  url("https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-images/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg") right;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="Formulario.html">Formulario</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Didn't know about this functionality! Thanks!